# Using regex for apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, regression

I am using this function

```
function capitalizeAllWords(str: string) {
  return str.replace(/\b\w/s, letter => letter.toUpperCase());
  }
```

Current result: Men's apparel

Required result: Men's Apparel

how to achieve this?

Comment: `/(?<='s )[a-z]/g` would do it.

Comment: Use `/(?:^|\s)\w/g`

Comment: depending on how the OP wants to handle word boundaries except from `'` something like this ... [`(?<!'|^)\b\w`](https://regex101.com/r/hiJIX3/1) ... or a less specific ... [`(?<!')\b\w`](https://regex101.com/r/hiJIX3/2) ... would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
function capitalizeAllWords(str: string) {
  return str.replace(/(?<![\w'])\w/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase());
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w']                    any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
```

Mind the `g` flag to replace all matches, not `s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback of the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) method.

```
function capitalizeAllWords(str: string) {
    return str.replace(/'[a-z]|\b([a-z])/g, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1.toUpperCase() : m);
}
```

Capture what you want to uppercase in group 1 (denoted by `g1` in the example code), and match what you want to leave untouched (denoted by `m` in the example code)

```
'[a-z]|\b([a-z])
```

**Explanation**

- `'[a-z]` Match `'` and a char a-z
- `|` Or
- `\b([a-z])` A word boundary `\b` to prevent a partial match, and capture a char a-z in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oGI1nP/1)

```js
const regex = /'[a-z]|\b([a-z])/g;
const str = "Men's apparel $test";
let res = str.replace(regex, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1.toUpperCase() : m);
console.log(res);
```